# x86_64 and memory issues

Tags: ubuntu, memory

Recently I've switched from ubuntu 32bit to 64bit version. And now I experiencing some problems.

All application take twice more memory. And some application takes even more. For example sshd on new server:

```
root      6608  0.0  0.0  67972  2912 ?        Ss   14:43   0:00 sshd: deploy [priv]
deploy    6616  0.0  0.0  67972  1724 ?        S    14:43   0:00 sshd: deploy@pts/4
root     20892  0.0  0.0  50916  1160 ?        Ss   15:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     21170  0.0  0.0  67972  2912 ?        Ss   15:56   0:00 sshd: deploy [priv]
deploy   21173  0.0  0.0  67972  1728 ?        S    15:56   0:00 sshd: deploy@pts/0
root     23802  0.0  0.0  67972  2912 ?        Ss   16:08   0:00 sshd: deploy [priv]
deploy   23804  0.0  0.0  67972  1724 ?        S    16:08   0:00 sshd: deploy@pts/1
root     24570  0.0  0.0  67972  2908 ?        Ss   12:45   0:00 sshd: deploy [priv]
deploy   24573  0.0  0.0  68112  1804 ?        S    12:45   0:00 sshd: deploy@pts/3
deploy   25014  0.0  0.0   5168   852 pts/0    S+   16:13   0:00 grep ssh
```

the same on the old server:

```
root      4867  0.0  0.0   5312  1028 ?        Ss   Mar23   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     23753  0.0  0.0   8052  2556 ?        Ss   16:15   0:00 sshd: deploy [priv]
deploy   23755  0.0  0.0   8052  1524 ?        S    16:15   0:00 sshd: deploy@pts/0
deploy   23770  0.0  0.0   3004   748 pts/0    D+   16:15   0:00 grep ssh
```

The same problems with postfix, nginx and some other application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complex than this.

Yes, the 64bit executables are going to consume more ram as some of the basic building-blocks of programs are larger on a 64bit system.

However, looking at the output you've provided it isn't all that bad. Unless there's actual contention for physical memory, the RSS (Resident Set Size, the part of a process which are in physical RAM) column is more appropriate, and looking at your output it's a lot less than a doubling of RAM consumption.

A more comprehensive discussion on memory usage can be found here: [Understanding memory usage on linux](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html)

Comment: Does this issue has any relations with vm.overcommit_memory ?

Comment: No, I don't believe this is related to vm.overcommit_memory. overcommit is giving the kernel room to allow malloc-requests even if it'd exceed available memory in the hope that it won't actually be used/needed, if you were to disable overcommit, you'd probably end up with applications exiting needlessly because of denied memory allocation-requests.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to 64 bits. Since default data types are twice the size, as are default instruction sizes, in-memory images will be consequently larger.

**EDIT**: A few (not SSH) programs are not well adapted to 64 bit systems. In one case a well-known UPS vendor's power monitoring daemon ballooned from an already large 400M to a huge 1.5G when run on a 64 bit Java runtime. Their response to the bug report was to tell me to run it on 32 bit Java. :)

Comment: So if I had 4Gb RAM on my old host with 32bit system, it's the same as new host with 64bit and 8Gb of RAM? So what's a point?

Comment: In the end the point is twofold: first of all, you don't run x86_64 for nothing. Have a reason to do so, like have a *lot* of RAM: a i386 kernel doesn't support that by default. Second is that there are other pretty large downsides to running 8GiB on a i386 architecture, like having to map ZONE_HIGH in ZONE_NORMAL when using a lot of RAM.

Comment: So in case of 8gb what would perform better. One 64bit instance or two 32bit instances with balancing?

Comment: And one more thing. Why the difference is so big. I mean with the example with sshd. 8mb vs 67mb?

Comment: No, its not that bad. First of all, only some processes are double in size, most see only a percentage gain. Secondly, as Kjetil pointed out, only the RSS portion is resident in memory, the rest of the program text is paged up off of the filesystem as needed. As a result most of the startup code pages gets discarded and no longer takes up any RAM.

Comment: SSH size depends on what it is doing and how long it has run. Running ps aux on a 64 bit system, I see sizes from 708 to 5068K, but median is 784K.

Comment: Running two operating systems has its own overhead, including YOUR overhead of administering two systems.